# How do I make an asynchronous HTTP request in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

How do I asynchronously send a HTTP request with POST method and some variables to a page, like it was opened in a browser?

I integrated my login system with my forum's, but, to complete the login, the user must be redirected to the forum and then back to the current page. This is a kind of killer for my iPhone web app.

With this request I need to send some POST variables so the login can actually take place.
How do I do this in JavaScript and/or jQuery?

**Edit**: According to the jQuery AJAX library examples, this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/forum/ucp?mode=login",
    data:
    ({
        username : $("#username").first().val(),
        password : $("#password").first().val(),
        autologin : $("#autologin").first().val(),
        viewonline : $("#viewonline").first().val(),
        redirect : window.location
    }),
    success: function(msg)
    {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

But guess what? It doesn't!

Comment: I must say, unless I misinterpreted the question, it's easily solved with Google!

Comment: I have tried... I cannot find anything that works.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: "user=bob&password=pass",
        success: function(data) {
            //function called when the server responds
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe if you explain a little it will help

Comment: Here are the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . It sends an AJAX POST request to login.php with parameters user=bob and password=pass, and calls the function specified by `success` when it's done.

Comment: I have added my code to my question... Which doesn't work... :(

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Do you get any error messages in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Just use an XMLHttpRequest object. This object is native to JavaScript. There is plenty of instructions for this class on the web.

Comment: IE makes it a pain in the arse though. If at all possible, use jQuery's implementation as @waitinforatrain has shown.

Comment: It is for iPhone app so ie should not be a concern. I take your point though.